# Solve the recurrence relation. Need some help

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

x(n)= x(n-1) + 2*n + 3 ; Given x(0)=4;

I'm using backwards substitution

x(n-1)= [x(n-2) + 2(n-1) + 3] + 2*n+ 3

x(n-2)= [x(n-3) + 2(n-2) + 3] + x(n-2) + 2(n-1) + 3 + 2*n + 3 so on and so forth......

so i write the general expression as :

x(n) = x(n-i) + [something here] + i*3
but i am not sure because i'm getting terms like 2(n-3) + 2(n-2) + 2(n-1)+ 2(n) ...

do i write these terms as (2-i-1) ?

any help will be appreciated

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What is $x$ with no index?

Comment: i think there must be an index

Comment: You've written $x_n=x_{n-1}+2x+3$.  What is the meaning of the term "$2x$"?  For example, you tell us that $x_0=4$ so what is $x_1$?

Comment: Sorry that will be 2*n not x. Fixing it

Comment: Fixed it now! Please check

Comment: Have you tried listing the first few terms to see if you can spot a pattern?

Comment: Yes I have got the pattern for the first & 3rd term, just the second one I'm getting like ......(2n-3), 2n-2, 2n-1,2n. Should the pattern be 2n-i ? Or some summation?

Comment: Not following.  You said that $x_0=4$.  What is $x_1$?  What is $x_2$?   You should always list a few terms of any recurrence you are studying.

Comment: Only x(0) is given in the question. Basically everything else will cancel out leaving x(n-n) which is x(0).

Comment: For Heaven's sakes.  You have a recurrence, use it!  $x_1=x_0+2\times 1 +3$ so $x_1=?$

Comment: What part are you talking about dude? You will know what I am saying when you do it with pen & paper. You don't need x(1) here. I'm just asking about the general expression

Comment: I give up.  Good luck.

Comment: The suggestion is: before trying to find a general formula, just calculate $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, maybe $x_4$ by hand, as actual numbers. Once you have those numbers, you might be able to *guess* a formula for $x_n$; it is much easier to prove that a particular formula is correct than to find the formula to begin with. Regardless of whether you end up succeeding, this is an approach that you should always try.

Comment: @lulu You are behaving like some high mind entitled mathematician. Matter of fact is you are not. I gave the question as is from the test & you are mad because you don't like the question. Wtf lol.

Comment: Sam, I know that lulu's impatience showed in their comments, and you might well be upset by that. But the fact remains that you are asking people to volunteer their time to help you; so I suggest not insulting people on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Indeed, you were going in the right track !!!.

\begin{align}
x_{n} & = x_{n - 1} + 2n + 3 =
x_{n - 2} + \bracks{2\pars{n - 1} + 3} + \pars{2n + 3}
\\[5mm] & =
x_{n - 3} + \bracks{2\pars{n - 2} + 3} + \bracks{2\pars{n - 1} + 3} +
\pars{2n + 3} = \cdots =\
\overbrace{\quad x_{0}\quad}^{\ds{=\ 4}} + \sum_{k = n}^{1}\pars{2k + 3}
\\[5mm] & =
4 + 2\,{n\pars{n + 1} \over 2} + 3n = n^{2} + 4n + 4 = \bbx{\pars{n + 2}^{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Omg thank you! Finally I can rest now :D

Comment: @Sam Sure you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

make for your series the Ansatz $$x_n=A+Bn+Cn^2$$

Comment: Yes at first I tried that but it's mentioned to do with the back substitution method. By the way which term should I consider Cn^2 in my given expression?

Comment: $$A,B,C$$ are real numbers, you must insert numbers of your sequnce to compute this numbers

Comment: Probably can't break this equation to quadratic

Comment: $$x_0=4$$ then you will get $$A=4$$ etc.

Comment: Ok let me try! Thanks

Comment: should i post you the solution?

Comment: If you can it will be very helpful. I got it in my test but couldn't do...

Comment: it is $$x_n=4+4n+n^2$$

Comment: Ok let me try to solve it. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: if you Need further assistance please let me know it

Comment: Sure thing! :) I think I can do it now

Comment: Hi, can you please give the proper breakdown of the substitution? I'm getting this - http://imgur.com/2bFkbcu